# How to rebuild go golang application with fresh or air?

Tags: docker, go

gravityblast/fresh and cosmtrek/air are not rebuilding main.go, when i change files from local volume. Where im wrong? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuQqatSTO7w

Dockerfile

```
# create image from the official Go image
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk add --update tzdata \
    bash wget curl git nano;
# Create binary directory, install glide and fresh
RUN mkdir -p $$GOPATH/bin && \
    # curl https://glide.sh/get | sh && \
    # go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
    curl -fLo ~/.air https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/bin/linux/air && \
    chmod +x ~/.air

# define work directory
ADD . /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app


# serve the app1
CMD ~/.air -c air.conf

RUN chmod -R 0777 $GOPATH/src
```

Comment: Don't comment out lines which are part of a continuous multi-line statement. The first trailing back-slash joins the commented line that follows which effectively comments out the entire remaining part of the compound statement.

Comment: @colminator I did it, but nothing has changed. Watch the video, please youtube.com/watch?v=GuQqatSTO7w

Comment: wasn't suggesting this was your root cause - but just a potential gotcha for your testing. Re your video - you are developing on Windows and using a Linux-based docker-container. I would suspect there is some filesystem notifications that are lost when going from one OS to the other. I've expanded on this in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From similar issues: https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/issues/292

FS notify events are not triggered by host Windows file updates:

> I'm not sure how Docker for Windows is mounting the shared folder, but
>   generally file shares ... don't support notifications.

This issue does not appear to affect MacOS or Linux hosts.

If you must be on Windows, perhaps this package may help:

- https://github.com/zippoxer/docker-windows-volume-watcher

```
Usage of docker-windows-volume-watcher:

  -container string
        Name of the container instance that you wish to notify of filesystem changes

  -delay int
        Delay in milliseconds before notifying about a file that's changed (default 100)

  -ignore string
        Semicolon-separated list of directories to ignore. Glob expressions are supported. (default "node_modules;vendor")

  -path string
        Root path where to watch for changes
```